# angular cannot load subpage

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Body of my index page looks in the following way:

```
<body >
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

I config my app in this way:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
  .state('main', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'main.html'
  })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

The content of my main.html file is:

```
<div>
    Example content
</div>
```

I would like my page to dispaly the content of main file when entering the main address. However, it is blank. What am I missing (I am new to angular)?

Comment: is there an error in the console?

Comment: no, there isn't

Comment: How do you bootstrap the app? there is no ng-app on the body at your example, so I guess its at the config too. more code would be helpful.